# How manage dependencies of a self-contained/portable PowerShell script?

Tags: git, powershell, github, dependencies

I'm working in a PowerShell script that I want to distribute to my friends (and other people, open source).

This script has dependencies on third-party modules and other modules that I wrote myself.

The thing is: I want to distribute it "self-contained", I don't want people to need to "`Install-Module`" in order for my script to work. They should be able to simply run it.

I thought about creating a folder called "modules" in my script folder, where I would put all the `.psm1` files that my script depends on, and running `Import-Module ".\modules\ScriptName.psm1"` in my script. Then, I could distribute this entire project folder.

The problem, then, is: how to manage these dependencies? Is there a way I can get them automatically updated when any of them gets an update? Will I have to manually update every file? I also don't really need my git repository to actually track changes in these module files, since each module has its own repository.

I'm open to suggestions in other/better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Package the dependencies alongside your own code? It would be self contained then. If you had an update in dependencies you would just update the module and bump the version?

https://github.com/ModuleBuild/ModuleBuild - I use this for a similar case and I then have an ADO feed with that module available there.

Comment: @SebastianWiszowaty
That's what I thought, but as I asked, how to manage these dependencies? Is there a way I can get them automatically updated when any of them gets an update? Will I have to manually update every file? I also don't really need my git repository to actually track changes in these module files, since each module has its own repository.

I don't know if the suggested ModuleBuild solves these problems?

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that specific for powershell, possibly some sort of github dependabot in case these modules are published on github. I remember reading something about nuget supporting this kind of dependency tracking, but haven't looked into it.

For me I work only with internal modules so I can have yaml triggers made when a new nuget is published of module A and it's a dependency of module B and then module B is built with new version of A... Now that I think about it, you could just have a trigger auto-upload new nuget of public module when it's available to trigger.